# How to use Xamarin Forms Custom Button Renderer's Touch event to change the Buttons Image

Tags: xaml, xamarin, custom-controls

I figured it out. 
For anyone needing this. Please see the following.
After Watching [Xamarin Evolve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIZ8G47KPIM) a million times I caught on.

```
class LoginButtonCustomRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Android.Widget.Button thisButton = Control as Android.Widget.Button;

        thisButton.Touch += (object sender, TouchEventArgs e2) =>
        {
            if (e2.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TouchDownEvent");

                // Had to use the e.NewElement
                e.NewElement.Image = "pressed.png";
            }
            else if (e2.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TouchUpEvent");
            }
        };

    }

}
```

Comment: don't forget `thisButton.Touch -= ...` else you'll have some memory leaks

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about that.

Comment: When do we supposed to do `thisButton.Touch -= ...` ???

Comment: @JonathanMoss Click event of xamarin button has stopped working after this implementation, only for android, not iOS. Furthermore, android click event button animations are also not working anymore. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Well, and Click event is Touch down followed by Touch up.
When registering the Touch event, it is being handled, and therefore, the click event won't be fired.

The solution is to set e.Handled = false; in the Touch event.

Answer (score 0):

you need call

Control.CallOnClick();

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample how to implement a two state ImageButton in Xamarin Forms:

PCL:

```
public class FancyButton : Button
{
    public void SendClickedCommand()
    {
        ICommand command = this.Command;
        if (command != null)
        {
            command.Execute(this.CommandParameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Android render:

```
public class FancyButtonAndroid : ButtonRenderer
{
    Android.Widget.Button thisButton;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        thisButton = Control as Android.Widget.Button;
        thisButton.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.btn_unpress);
        thisButton.Touch += ThisButton_Touch;
        thisButton.Click += HandleButtonClicked;
    }

    private void ThisButton_Touch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
        if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TouchDownEvent");
            thisButton.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.btn_press);
        }
        else if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TouchUpEvent");
            thisButton.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.btn_unpress);
        }
    }

    private void HandleButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Element != null && Element is FancyButton)
        {
            (Element as FancyButton).SendClickedCommand();
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (thisButton != null)
        {
            thisButton.Touch -= ThisButton_Touch;
            thisButton.Click -= HandleButtonClicked;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Note: in the Touch event set: `e.Handled = false;` to cause the Click event to rise.