# xamarin forms ButtonRenderer onclick override

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In XAMARIN FORMS `ButtonRenderer` only provide two methods which i can override: `OnElementChanged` and `OnElementPropertyChanged`. Which method do I want to override to handle button clicks?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is what OP is asking. Please forgive me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a reference to the button in your Renderer (search for the proeprty `Control`). Just add the click-event/listener/command for this `Control` (but be carefull, it may be that the `Control` is `NULL`, depending on your renderer implementation).

Quick code sample for ios (depends on your renderer):

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyButtonRenderer> e)
{
    var mybutton = Control as UIButton;
    mybutton.TouchUpInside += (s, args) => { /* your logic */};
}
```

For android you can find a [sample on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37255469/2653134).

Comment: you are amazing thanks for this great help now i can show Interstitial ads every time i click on button.

protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e){
base.OnElementChanged(e);
   var btn = Control as UIButton;
   btn.AllTouchEvents += async (s, args) =>
   {
    adView = new Interstitial(AdmobID);
    adView.LoadRequest(Request.GetDefaultRequest());
    do{ await Task.Delay(1);
    } while (!adView.IsReady);
    InvokeOnMainThread(() => adView.PresentFromRootViewController(UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController));

   };}

Comment: @AbdullahTahan I'm glad I could help. Please mark as answered, that other users see that the question is solved